# Issue with get_yticklabels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to plot a bar graph, and I am experiencing an issue when I try to access the labels (both on the X and Y axis) to change them. In particular, this code:

```
fig = plot.figure(figsize=(16,12), dpi=(300))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_ylabel("simulated quantity")
ax1.set_xlabel("simulated peptides - from most to least abundant")

# create the bars, and set a different color for the bars referring to experimental peptides
barlist = ax1.bar( numpy.arange(len(quantities)), [numpy.log10(x) for x in quantities] )
for index, peptide in enumerate(peptides) :
        if peptide in experimentalPeptidesP or peptide in experimentalPeptidesUP :
                barlist[index].set_color('b')

labelsY = ax1.get_yticklabels(which='both')
print "These are the label objects on the Y axis:", labelsY
print "These are the labels on the Y axis:", [item.get_text() for item in ax1.get_xticklabels(    which='both')]
for label in labelsY : label.set_text("AAAAA")
ax1.set_yticklabels(labelsY)
```

Gives the following output:

```
These are the label objects on the Y axis: <a list of 8 Text yticklabel objects>
These are the labels on the Y axis: [u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
```

And the resulting figure has "AAAAA" as the text of every label on the Y axis, as requested. My issue is, while I am able to correctly SET the labels, apparently I cannot GET their text...and the text should exist, because if I don't replace the labels with "AAAAA" I get the following figure:
[image]

As you can see, there are labels on the Y axis, and I'd need to "get" their text. Where is the error?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT**: Thanks to Mike Müller's answer, I managed to make it work. Apparently, in my case invoking draw() is not enough, I have to get the values AFTER saving the figure using savefig(). It might depend on matplotlib's version, I am running 1.5.1 and Mike is running 1.5.0 . I will also take a look at FuncFormatter, as suggested below by tcaswell

Comment: Because those objects are replaced by the ticker/formatter machinery.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Read the labels on the Y axis that are automatically placed (in the example above, "0.0", "0.5", "1.0", ...), and replace them with pow(10, 0.0), pow(10, 0.5), pow(10, 1.0), ...

Comment: Mpl has log scale for the axis built in which takes care of this sort of thing for you.  Other wise use FuncFormatter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to render the plot first to actually get labels. Adding a `draw()`works:

```
plot.draw()
labelsY = ax1.get_yticklabels(which='both')
```

Without:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,12), dpi=(300))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
p = ax1.bar(range(5), range(5))

>>> [item.get_text() for item in ax1.get_yticklabels(which='both')]
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

and with `draw()`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,12), dpi=(300))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
p = ax1.bar(range(5), range(5))
plt.draw()

>>> [item.get_text() for item in ax1.get_yticklabels(which='both')]
['0.0', '0.5', '1.0', '1.5', '2.0', '2.5', '3.0', '3.5', '4.0']
```

Comment: Hi! I tried to add a "plot.draw()" line before collecting the labels, but apparently the result is the same. I get the 8 objects, but I cannot visualize their text.

Comment: What version are you using? I got it to work with 1.5.0.

Comment: 1.5.1 ; but thanks to your advice, I managed to make it work. Apparently, I just need to get the labels after I *SAVE* the figure using savefig(), and the text appears...meaning that I will have to save it twice :-D Weird...maybe it's because I never invoke show() ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Copy-paste problem. Fixed.